# How to change characters of a string into '*'

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a simple Wheel of fortune type game. But I'm having a serious issue getting started. I'm just trying to convert my phrase into "*" so that it can't be seen until the user guesses what one of the letters is. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Puzzle
{
    private String solution="DOG PILE";
    private StringBuilder puzzle;



    public Puzzle(String solution)
    {

        int startindex=puzzle.indexOf(solution);
        puzzle.replace(startIndex, endIndex, "-");

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Umm... you never declare the endIndex variable.

Comment: What about `solution.replaceAll(".", "*")`?

Comment: @RohitJain: Probably many. I see an NPE, an undeclared variable and wrong logic with the replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression and replace method:

```
String hideSolution = solution.replaceAll(".", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public static String hide(String data, StringBuilder charactersToShow) {
    return data.replaceAll("[^\\s" + charactersToShow.toString() + "]", "*");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder gueses = new StringBuilder();
    String solution = "DOG PILE";

    System.out.println(hide(solution, gueses));//

    gueses.append('D');
    System.out.println(hide(solution, gueses));

    gueses.append('I');
    System.out.println(hide(solution, gueses));
}
```

Output:

```
*** ****
D** ****
D** *I**
```

**Little explanation**:

`replaceAll` method takes two arguments: *regular expression* that describes what part of String should be replaced, and second argument is replacement. Result of that method is new String so original String will not be changed.

As regular expression I used class of characters `[]` with negation `[^...]` so it will match any character that is not in this class. Besides user characters I added `\\s` at the beginning, because it represents every white space (normal spaces, tabulators, new lines, and so on) since you probably don't want to replace them with `*`.

You may also want to add `'` into that "set" if you don't want to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Use guava library

example:

```
String noDigits = CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.replaceFrom(string, "*"); // star out all digits
```